# Generate insert statement from resultset in Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

In Joomla 2.5 and 3.0 I am able to get the database result set as an array. Is it possible to convert this array as sql insert statement or .sql file so that the same can be used to insert  in another table of same structure in another database?

Comment: could you please provide an example of your code you are using to get a result from the database. will help getting a more specific answer ;)

Comment: You can Use file for writing the array content that should contain the proper query format.

Comment: Thanks, I have similar code as provided in below answer. I would like to export _data as .sql file in joomla so that I can email it to the admin of target database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, Check the code below. You can use the Joomla core function to get this done.

1st initialize a data set as below.

```
function initializesData()
    {
        $this->_data->id        = 0;
        $this->_data->field1    = '';        
        $this->_data->field2    = '';
        $this->_data->field3    = 1;

        return $this->_data;
    }
```

Then load the row into the data set as below.

```
function &getOne($id='')
    {
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();       
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from($db->nameQuote(TABLE_PREFIX.'table_name'));
        $query->where($db->nameQuote('id').'='.$db->Quote($id));       
        $db->setQuery($query);      
        $this->_data = $db->loadObject();

        if ($this->_data)
        {      
            return $this->_data;
        }

    }
```

Then insert the row using Joomla tables.

```
 function store()
    {  
       //Get post data 
       $this->_data = $this->getOne($id);


       $row = &$this->getTable('table_name');


       if (!$row->bind($this->_data))
       {
          $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());          
          return false;
       } 


       if (!$row->check())
       {         
         $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
         return false;
       } 


       if (!$row->store())
       {
         $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
         return false;
       }      
       $new_id = $this->_db->insertId();

       if($new_id > 0)
            $this->_data->id = $new_id;

       return true;
    }
```

All above functions are in the model. Hope you can manage function calls in the controller. If you want to do multiple insertions loops the function calls. If you have any issue let me know

Comment: Thanks. The requirement is to export _data to an .sql file as insert statement. I need to give it as .sql file as I don't have access to the target database.

Comment: in the question it says "Is it possible to convert this array as sql insert statement". Never mind. Let me look into your problem